# Global or local when creating a function

Tags: c, function, global, local

Hey I'm trying to write a basic assembler it doesn't even do real machine language,
the premise is to learn how to code in c ansi 90.

I have made a function that gets a string that supposedly has an instruction
from a set of 16(mov, cmp, jmp,...), and I need to compare the string to know if
its truly a one of the instructions.

I made a local two-dimensional array of char in the function with all the 16 instructions,
and I use this array to compare to the string and send back a number depicting the instruction if found equal.

this function will be used almost all the time, and the assembler needs to be fast if for instance it needs to assemble a source code with millions of instructions.

should I change the array from local to global will it change anything?

Thanks.

Edit: the code.

```
command_type is_command(char * string)
{
    int i;
    command_type type = NAN;
    char * command_names[] = {"mov", "cmp", "add", "sub", "not",
                              "clr", "lea", "inc", "dec", "jmp",
                              "bne", "get", "prn", "jsr", "rts",
                              "hlt"};
    
    for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        if(!strcmp(string, command_names[i]))
        {
            type = i + 1;
        }
    }
    
    return type;
}
```

Comment: The strictly correct answer is: Try it out and benchmark the difference. Especially because you haven't shown us any code we can only guess at what you have really done

Comment: It's even possible that an entirely different approach would be a far faster solution, e.g.: just having a `switch` statement (see e.g.: http://craftinginterpreters.com/scanning-on-demand.html#tries-and-state-machines)

Comment: If you never modify the array, the compiler may notice this and compile it as a static variable, so it doesn't matter how you write it in your code. I suggest you not worry about this too much.

Comment: Why C90?  That's probably quite a bit older than you are, and has not been the current standard for the whole of the current millennium.  You should be learning C18 (essentially the same as C11), or perhaps C99 though that's less than ideal.  But C90 is archaic and allows you to learn sloppy C programming styles that the more recent C standards do not permit.

Comment: Unless the set of instructions changes, the array should be `static const char instructions[][8] = { "mov", "cmp", "jmp", … };` and then it will probably be about as efficient as it can be.

Comment: Using a 'linear search' to translate the three letter string to a number will be slow... If the three letter op array were sorted, you could at least benefit from a binary search of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the contents of the strings will not change, declare the element type `const`. Since the addresses of the strings will not change, declare the pointer type `const`.

Since the array is needed throughout the entire execution of the program, declare it `static`.

```
static const char * const command_names[] = {
        "mov", "cmp", "add", "sub", "not",
        "clr", "lea", "inc", "dec", "jmp",
        "bne", "get", "prn", "jsr", "rts",
        "hlt"
    };
```

In general, the more information you give the compiler about something, the better a job it can do.